# How to check DBNull value in Linq query results

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am using the below code and trying to group by Currency and Code. After this I am trying to loop through the result set.

But the issue is while looping through the results, at the end I am getting the below exception on the for each statement:

**Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.**

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var result = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
               result r by new
               {
                    currency = r.Field<String>("CURRENCY"),
                    Code = r.Field<String>("CODE")
               }
              into grp
              select new
              {
                   currency = grp.Key.currency,
                   Code = grp.Key.Code,
                   amount = grp.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x["AMOUNT"]))
              };

    foreach (var obj in result)
    {
      String sCurr =obj.currency;
      String Code = obj.Code;
      string amount= obj.amount.ToString());
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is the amount an actual double value, or a string representation of a double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
 amount = grp.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x["AMOUNT"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : x["AMOUNT"]));
```

If that is the line that is giving you the problem.

Comment: The built-in `Field` extension method will deal with `DBNull.Value` just fine if you give it a `Nullable<>` type parameter, so you don't need to check for `DBNull.Value` manually. Instead, you can handle an ordinary C# `null`, which lets you use the `??` operator for more concise code.

Comment: Thnaks Sam Ward, the issue is with the conversion, It also mentioned by Thom Smith.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
amount = grp.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x["AMOUNT"]))
```

will not work as you expect. If `x["AMOUNT"]` is `DBNull.Value` instead of a valid `double`, the conversion will fail with an exception. Instead, try:

```
amount = grp.Sum(x.Field<double?>("AMOUNT"))
```

if you expect that field to be a `double`. `Sum` will treat the `null` values as zero, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355137%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Thom Smith, the conversion was causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

The way to find the number of CELLS with DBNulls for a specific column:

```
int numOfEmptyColA = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(p=>p.IsNull("ColA")).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which one is getting the error, but you can can compare it to `DBNull.Value` like so.

```
String sCurr = obj.currency == DBNull.Value ? "" : obj.currency;
```

Comment: The above code is giving a compilation error like "cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' to 'System.DBNull'

Comment: Then it's probably the amount field.  I wasn't sure which was getting the error.  So, try adding it to the `obj.amount` expression, and remove it from the other two.

Comment: `string amount= obj.currency == DBNull.Value ? "" : obj.amount.ToString();`

Comment: I think the syntax is String sCurr = (object)obj.currency == DBNull.Value ? "" : obj.currency; But still I am getting the same error. I have added similar check for other two fields. but the exception is at  foreach (var obj in group)

Comment: You should remove the DBNull.Value comparison from the first two expressions.  Only use it for the amount.