# Get the sum of column using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to implement the following SQL statement using entity framework:

```
select coalesce(SUM(cdin_ActMortgageAmnt), 0) 
from CRM.dbo.CDIndex,CRM.dbo.company  
where comp_companyid = cdin_companyid 
  and comp_idcust like '%10319%' 
  and cdin_Deleted is null 
  and cdin_startunstufdate is not null 
  and cdin_Status = 'InProgress'
```

I tried to get the sum of `cdin_ActMortgageAmnt`:

```
Company c = db.Companies.Find(750);  

var CGP = (from cd in db.CDIndexes  
           join com in db.Companies on cd.cdin_CompanyId equals com.Comp_CompanyId  
           where com.Comp_IdCust == c.Comp_IdCust &&  
                 cd.cdin_Deleted == null &&  
                 cd.cdin_startunstufdate == null &&  
                 cd.cdin_Status == "InProgress"  
           select new  
                 {  
                     act = cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt == null ? 0 : cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt 
                 }  
          );  

var query = CGP.Sum(x => x.act);  
lblSum.Text = query.ToString();
```

But the query returns null while tracing...

Comment: What is the generated SQL query? (the `ToString()` value from your `CGP` object, or see it via SQL Server Profiler). Without it we cannot be of that much assistance.

Comment: Thank you for reply ,
the the result from the sql query is the sum of the column = 72587.765420

Comment: I think if act is nullable in SQL Table, you can replace null by zero for null value befor the sum

Comment: CGP.Sum(x => x.act  == DBNull.Value ? 0 : x.act);

Comment: `Sum` in Linq will be converted to `SUM` in SQL which handles `NULL` values in a safe manner, so that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: But please post the actual **generated** query.

Comment: Thank you all for notice, i update the code for null value issue in my question.
@ArDumez i tried to do sum in the way you mentioned but it gives null value when i trace?

Comment: DbNull.Value is not the same value that simple null

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711675/how-to-check-dbnull-value-in-linq-query-results

Comment: @ArDumez i tried to figure out the information in the link but it gives me an error? ` var xx= CGP.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal( x.act==DBNull.Value?0:x.act));`

Comment: I really need a help i'm at work